# php simple html dom question

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Here are some codes, how to get the `div[class=title]` and the nearest `<p>` content? I only know how to get the `div[class=title]` in a foreach, but no idea how to get the `p`. Thanks.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
require_once("simple_html_dom.php");
?>
<?php
$str = <<<ETO
<div id="content">
<div class="title"><p>text1</p></div>
<p>destriction1</p>
<p>destriction2</p>
<div class="title"><p>text2</p></div>
<p>destriction3</p>
<p>destriction4</p>
<p>destriction5</p>
<div class="title"><p>text3</p></div>
<p>destriction6</p>
<p>destriction7</p>
</div>
ETO;
$html = str_get_html($str);
foreach($html->find("div[class=title]") as $content){
    echo $content.'<hr />';
}
?>
```

I want output like:

```
text1
destriction1
destriction2
------------------------------
text2
destriction3
destriction4
destriction5
------------------------------
text3
destriction6
destriction7
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried a selector like `div[class=title] p`?

```
$html = str_get_html($str);
foreach($html->find("div[class=title] p") as $content){
    echo $content.'<hr />';
}
```

The children() function should also work (shown below)

That will get you the `<p>` in each title div, although not the following paragraphs.  To do that, use the [next_sibling() function](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_traverse).  Something like this:

```
$html = str_get_html($str);
foreach($html->find("div[class=title]") as $content){
    // $content = <div class="title">.  first_child() should be the <p>
    echo $content->first_child().'<hr />';

    // Get the <p>'s following the <div class="title">
    $next = $content->next_sibling();
    while ($next->tag == 'p') {
        echo $next.'<hr />';
        $next = $next->next_sibling();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for a best teach.